# How to find the Previous MonthName using Monthname in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find Stock of Previous Monthname.Here is my code.

PHP:

```
$month='April'
```

MYSQL Table:

```
            Stock
Bot_Name    March      April
XYZ         25000      15000
```

SQL Query:`SELECT MONTHNAME($month,INTERVAL -1 MONTH) FROM STOCK.`

Expected Output:

```
March
25000
```

Above Query is not working, I had no idea where I am going wrong.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying something with php ?

```
$lastMonthName = date("F", strtotime("last month"));
$sql = "SELECT $lastMonthName FROM STOCK"
```